# Converting variables to factor in R when each variable has its own total levels in a loop

Tags: r, loops, character

I have 116 character variables and each have their own number of unique levels. Some have only two levels (e.g. `A` & `B`) while others have 327 levels. I can convert them into `factor`s one by one by using this code:

```
#train_cat <- training dataset
#cat1 <- character variable

dist <- length(unique(train_cat$cat1))
x <- seq(1, dist)
cat1 <- factor(train_cat$cat1, labels = x)
```

However, I would like to be able to make these changes within a loop as the character variables are named `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3`, ..., `cat116`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for loop`.

I assume that you need `dist` just to label the factors with numbers and afterwards not anymore. As well I will assume in my example code, that all variables are switched to factors. If this is not the case, you have to apply the function just to the subgroup.

The For loop would look like this:

```
for (var in names(train_cat)){
   fact <- factor(train_cat[var], labels=seq(1,length(unique(train_cat[var])))
   assign(var, fact)  
}
```

A other option would be to use `apply`, while in the `for loop` each `factor` was made to an own `variable` in this way, you will get a new `data.frame` with all the variables.

With `apply` it would work like this:

```
fact <- apply(train_cat, 2,function(x){factor(x,labels = seq(1,length(unique(x))))})
cat_vars <- data.frame(fact)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner:

```
x <- data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                cat1 = sample(letters[1:3], size = 10, replace = T), 
                cat2 = sample(letters[1:3], size = 10, replace = T))

x[,grep("cat", colnames(x))] <-  data.frame(lapply(x[,grep("cat", colnames(x))], factor))
```